# Excel 2013, how to us the "search" function like vlookup

Tags: excel, class, search, formula, vlookup

Essentially, I am looking for a way to use the "search" function like the "vlookup" function. In my case, I am have a long list, of say, 1000 descriptions of different types of fasteners and I want to classify them according to what they are, (ie. Nut, bolt, washer etc.). However, I can't sort by description or partnumber because they, alphanumerically, don't line up by class. But he descripotion field does say at some point in it, what it is(ie. Nut, bolt, washer etc.).
As said, I have a table of classes, and I am looking for a formula that would look in the "description" field for all the values in the table,and then return that value, or one associated with it (like vlookup does with cell values).
So that, if it found "nut" in the description, it would return "nut", or if it found "bolt" it would return "bolt."

I hope that this question makes sense. Let me also say that I found a way "manually" do this using the search function, along with others, but the formula was very long and each value in my table had to be specially called out. However, I will include the formula I used to make clear what I was trying to do.
See below.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2,C3)),$G$2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3,C3)),$G$3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$4,C3)),$G$4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$5,C3)),$G$5,...IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$13,C3)),$G$13,"MISC"))))))))))))
```

You see that with each item you add to your table, you have to add another `if` loop. I am hoping there is a better way. (I would call it "vsearch" :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($G$3:$G$13,C3),$G$3:$G$13),"MISC")`

`SEARCH` returns an array of numbers or errors depending on whether each term is found in C3. By searching for "bignum" (in this case `2^15`) which won't be found, the match is always with the **last** number, i.e. the last matching term in G3:G13.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH` can be used to find the text, and `INDEX` can be used to return the text

using your example, where you are searching in `G`:

```
=MATCH("*"&C3&"*",$G:$G,0)
```

and then index to return the text

```
=INDEX($G:$G,MATCH("*"&C3&"*",$G:$G,0))
```

and as a finishing touch, the **#VALUE!** replacement

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G:$G,MATCH("*"&C3&"*",$G:$G,0)),"MISC")
```

Comment: This works if C3 is a "substring" of one of the col G values.....but I think it's the other way round. C3 contains a description which may contain one (or more?) of the substrings in G3:G13 - my answer works for that situation

Comment: @barryhoudini, you are right - I always get those mixed up (as I seem to always manage with `MATCH` too)